# How to make images a simple slider in js

Tags: javascript, html

i only know html, js and css. i'm trying to make the images change every couple of seconds., as in a slideshow.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var temp=1;
        function slider(){
            document.getElementById("pic1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("pic2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("pic3").style.display = 'none';
            if(temp==1){
                document.getElementById("pic1").style.display = 'block';
            }
            else if(temp==2){
                document.getElementById("pic2").style.display = 'block';
            }
            else if (temp==3){
                document.getElementById("pic3").style.display = 'block';
                temp=1;
            }
            temp++;
            setTimeout(slider(),25000);
        }
    </script>
```

the head is above, body below.

```
    <div id="rightside" onload="slider()">
        <a id="pic1"><img src="photos/hamilton/candyshop.jpg" style="display:block"></a>
        <a id="pic2"><img src="photos/hamilton/hamiltonboat.jpg" style="display:none"></a>
        <a id="pic3"><img src="photos/hamilton/waterduel.jpg" style="display:none"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: The best way, IMHO, is to make one long image. Then make the image the repeating background image of a DIV. Slide either the element, or the background position, to create your effect.

Comment: Are you getting any error at all? try wrapping the function in a `$(document).ready(function()` so you're sure the divs are loaded before start manipulating them

Comment: also consider switching to `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none` so it will save the space on the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in this that must all be fixed for it to work.

- In the line `setTimeout(slider(), 25000)`, you should pass `slider`, the function itself, not `slider()`, the return value of the function. Then you need to call `slider()` once after defining it to start the whole thing. You can do this in the JavaScript with `document.addEventListener` instead of the HTML with `onload`, making the HTML self-contained.
- You set the `img` to `display:none` in the HTML, and then you set the element with ID `pic1` to `display: block`. But this element isn’t the `img`, it’s the `a`. So you end up with a `display: block` `<a>` containing a `display: none` `<img>`, so nothing shows after all.
- When you set `temp = 1`, immediately after that you run `temp++`, so picture #1 is never seen again. `temp = 0` on that line would fix this, but it is better to make `temp` loop through “0, 1, 2” and use the modulo operator `%` that makes numbers loop if they are too high.

I also added `alt` attributes describing each of the images so the demo will work without the images loading. This would help your users too if they can’t see the images for whatever reason.

A working version:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var temp = 0;

  function slider() {
    document.getElementById("pic1").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("pic2").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("pic3").style.display = 'none';
    if (temp == 0) {
      document.getElementById("pic1").style.display = 'block';
    } else if (temp == 1) {
      document.getElementById("pic2").style.display = 'block';
    } else if (temp == 2) {
      document.getElementById("pic3").style.display = 'block';
    }
    temp = (temp + 1) % 3;
    setTimeout(slider, 1500); // decreased delay for demo purposes
  }

  slider();
});
```

```html
<div id="rightside">
  <a id="pic1" style="display:block">
    <img alt="candy shop" src="photos/hamilton/candyshop.jpg">
  </a>
  <a id="pic2" style="display:none">
    <img alt="Hamilton boat" src="photos/hamilton/hamiltonboat.jpg">
  </a>
  <a id="pic3" style="display:none">
    <img alt="water duel" src="photos/hamilton/waterduel.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

After getting the code working like the above, you can also reduce the repetition by using loops and functions. With the following version, if you add more pictures, you will only need to change one line of code instead of copying and pasting multiple parts of your code. Splitting your code up into functions that are each simple has the additional benefit that the code is easier to understand and to check for errors in.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var currentIndex = 0;
  var numPictures = 3;

  function slideshow() {
    hideAllPictures();
    showPicture(currentIndex);

    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % numPictures;
    setTimeout(slideshow, 1500);
  }

  function hideAllPictures() {
    for (var i = 0; i < numPictures; i++) {
      hidePicture(i);
    }
  }

  function hidePicture(index) {
    getPictureElement(index).style.display = 'none';
  }
  function showPicture(index) {
    getPictureElement(index).style.display = 'block';
  }

  function getPictureElement(index) {
    var id = "pic" + (index + 1);
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }

  slideshow();
});
```

```html
<div id="rightside">
  <a id="pic1" style="display:block">
    <img alt="candy shop" src="photos/hamilton/candyshop.jpg">
  </a>
  <a id="pic2" style="display:none">
    <img alt="Hamilton boat" src="photos/hamilton/hamiltonboat.jpg">
  </a>
  <a id="pic3" style="display:none">
    <img alt="water duel" src="photos/hamilton/waterduel.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using your second solution. it works perfectly fine. One minor comment, though. The first time it cycles through the pictures, it flashes white before switching. after each picture has been shown once, it transitions seamlessly.

Comment: Sorry, that might be due to my change to start the slideshow on the `DOMContentLoaded` event of `document` instead of `onload` of `div#rightside`. The carousel starts running right away, showing white where the picture would be in the moment before the picture is downloaded. Try replacing the first line with `document.getElementById('rightside').addEventListener('load', …` to act the same as the old `onload` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with Pure Javascript and CSS, change only `myimage*.jpg` to your image name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>My Simple Slider</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        .fading{
            -webkit-animation:fading 10s infinite;
            animation:fading 10s infinite
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes fading {
            0%{opacity:0}
            50%{opacity:1}
            100%{opacity:0
            }
        }

        @keyframes fading {
            0%{opacity:0}
            50%{opacity:1}
            100%{opacity:0
            }
        }
    </style>
    <body>

        <div>
            <p>Simple Image Carousel</p>

            <img class="mySlides fading" src="myimage1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides fading" src="myimage2.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides fading" src="myimage3.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides fading" src="myimage4.jpg" style="width:100%">

        </div>

        <script>
            var myIndex = 0;
            carousel();

            function carousel() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                myIndex++;
                if (myIndex > x.length) {
                    myIndex = 1
                }
                x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel, 9000);
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```